# PHP preg_replace square brackets

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, square-bracket

How could I replace some markup in this format:

```
[a href="/my_page" style="font-size: 13px"]click me[/a]
```

to

```
<a href="/my_page" style="font-size: 13px">click me</a>
```

using preg_replace()?

I will need to allow for more attributes as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity:  what's the point?

Comment: I'm trying to make a help topic section where a user can enter the topic content into a textbox, and also any HTML they want which gets saved into a database. But on outputting the topic content to the page, I will need to run htmlspecialchars() on the topic content, but don't want to replace any HTML markup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = '[a href="/my_page" style="font-size: 13px"]click me[/a]';
$ret = preg_replace('~\[([^\[\]]+)\]([^\[\]]++)\[/([^\[\]]++)\]~', '<\1>\2</\3>', $s);
```