# Passing var with square bracket into function, like this [1], brackets not recognized PHP 8.2

Tags: php, function, variables, substr, square-bracket

PHP 8.2: The last 3 hours I am searching for a solution to identify square brackets from a text.
In case I place the string text directly in the function, I can identify the square brackets:

```
    $Start = "[";
    $sHaystack = "This ist a test[2] looking for square brackets";
    echo "Haystack:". $sHaystack . "<br>";
    $position = mb_strpos($sHaystack,$Start);
    echo "Position of  ".$Start." in haystack is: ".$position."<br>";
```

Works perfectly.
It also works well using preg_replace().

But once the string is delivered into the function while doing the function call, it optically appears well when echoing the string, but the square brackets are not recognized neither with substr(), mb_substr(), preg_replace() and nothing else.

Meanwhile trying the same with this brackets "{" or "(" it works perfectly, also when entered while function call.

My reasoning went to the idea that in some manner the square brackets need to be escaped while the string is being sent into the function.

I already tried adding backslashes etc, but it does not work.
Has anyone got an idea?

This is the function ($sStart = "[" and $sEnd="]"):

```
function identifyBrackets($sHaystack,$sStart,$sEnd){

        // in case content is defined here it works. If entered via function call the square brackets are not identified.
    $sHaystack = "This ist a test[2] looking for square brackets";

        //test with preg_replace, if other brackets are delivered it works
    $what = ['~[[]~', '~[]]~'];
    $with = ['{', '}'];
    $sHaystack = preg_replace($what, $with, $sHaystack);

    echo "Haystack:<br> ".$sHaystack."<br>";

    $position = strpos($sHaystack,$sStart);
    echo "Position of  ".$sStart." in haystack is number: ".$position."<br>"; //with call via function no position found.

    return $sHaystack;
```

And yes, obviously I already searched all resources here on Stack Overflow, but they treat different problems:
[Capturing text between square brackets after a substring in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510759/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-after-a-substring-in-php)
[PHP preg_replace square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123447/php-preg-replace-square-brackets)
[How to replace any brackets for rounded brackets using Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636624/how-to-replace-any-brackets-for-rounded-brackets-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got the problem, when I runned file_get_contents here, some of the square brackets were html encoded:

[image]

So i guess you can use this regex to cover both ways, or search for the encoded characters: `&#91;` and `&#93;`

Regex: `&#91;|\[` for `[`

Regex: `&#93;|\]` for `]`

Comment: Thank you, Paolo. Unfortunately the (yes, true) wrongly spelled variables were not the cause, the reason is somewhere in passing the text via variable into the function. I also tried 
```
 $what = ['~[[]~', '~[]]~'];
 $with = ['{', '}'];
 $sHaystack = preg_replace($what, $with, $sHaystack);
 echo "Haystack after:<br> ".$sHaystack."<br>";
```

Comment: I edited the answer with a test i did here, if that doesnt' help, can you share the entire php file with what you are doing?

Comment: Probably I am one step further, I wanted to crawle random Wiki pages, like https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639 that have parts like this "Sie wurden nicht als Abkürzungen eingeführt,[1] da unter " (with the [1] upper position). They are in a class <sup id="cite_ref-locfaq_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-locfaq-1" title="">[1]</a></sup>. There is a probability that it's this, even though I did strip slashes before. However: this square brackets seem unrecocnizable.

Comment: The full context at the source where data comes in is this:  
  $sFullContent = file_get_contents($sUrl);
  $sFullContent = str_replace("[","{",$sFullContent);
  $sFullContent = str_replace("]","}",$sFullContent);
Echoing the $sFullcontent the higher placed cite marks are still in, while all other square brackets are replaced. Also after strip tags they are not changeable, but then they appear as normal square brackets (I thought they might be special chars, but seemingly not)

Comment: I edited the answer, take check if this is the problem

Comment: Thank you Paolo!! Great, in the "inspect" window this was not visible, so going deeper inside the Source was the solution.